# NullReference exception was unhandled by user code C#

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I am still learning to program in C# and working on a project in office

```
public static void SetIdentity(string subId)
{
    if (Proxy.ClientCredentials != null)
    {
        Proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = subId;// 
        Proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = subId;
    }

    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(customXertificateation);
}
```

This is where I get this exception: `NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code`

Can someone please take a look and suggest me what could be be wrong here?

Comment: `UserName` is probably null.

Comment: And what did your debugger tell you?  I can never understand why the majority of `NullReference` type exceptions are ever posted to SO when  it is *faster* to run your debugger which will tell you *what* is null.

Comment: A `NullReferenceException` cries for the debugger. _"I am still learning to program"_ Then now is the best time to [learn how to use it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: Have got at least the line Nº?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it  ....21k views and still, one of the most common issues posted.

Comment: `Proxy.ClientCredentials` is static class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check whether UserName is also not null

```
public static void SetIdentity(string subId)
{
    if (null != Proxy.ClientCredentials && null != Proxy.ClientCredentials.Username)
    {
        Proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = subId;// 
        Proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = subId;
    }

    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(customXertificateation);
}
```

Comment: [Check.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793957/nullreference-exception-was-unhandled-by-user-code-c-sharp#comment29424435_19793957)

Comment: It's funny because almost anything in this entire code block could be null...we don't even know what Proxy is.

Comment: Yoda conditions are so passé.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that the `UserName` member of the `Proxy.ClientCredentials` object is not null as well.  Something like this:

```
public static void SetIdentity(string subId)
{
    if (Proxy.ClientCredentials != null && Proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName != null)
    {
        Proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = subId;// 
        Proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = subId;
    }

    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(customXertificateation);
}
```

Comment: ok trying,, I just started with C# last month and this is my forst program ,, just bear with me guys ...

Comment: got it,,, debug step by step and found environment I was hitting wasnt configured correctly to accept username and password...